# Alibaba ActionTrail records disappearing

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I've started to notice that my actiontrail records are disappearing, and I can just find the most recent ones.

Is that some sort of issue? Are they being backed up somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the Alibaba CloudMonitor ActionTrail, I am pretty sure records are kept for no more than 30 days. So, if you can find your records within that time range, it is not a matter of disappearing, it is just how it works.